# Creating a list of Ints and functions Int -> Int -> Int

Tags: haskell

Apart from creating functions that do simple things to lists, I'm pretty new to haskell. I would like to create a list which contains things of type `Int`, and functions of type `Int -> Int -> Int`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
data Token = Value Int | Operator (Int -> Int -> Int)

tokens :: [Token]
tokens = [12, (+)]
```

but I get the following error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Token'
            with actual type `Integer -> Integer -> Integer'
In the expression: (+)
In the expression: [12, (+)]
In an equation for `tokens': tokens = [12, (+)]
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't work, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use your constructors to obtain values of type `Token`.  For example, `12` is not of type `Token`, it is of type `Int` (well, `Num a => a`).  Similarly, `(+)` is not a token but a function `Int -> Int -> Int`.  Notice that `Token /= Int -> Int -> Int`.

Fortunately you have defined a few constructors such as `Value :: Int -> Token` and `Operator :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Token`.  So using those we get:

```
tokens :: [Token]
tokens = [Value 12, Operator (+)]
```

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As said by Thomas, an `Int` or `Int->Int->Int` value can not have type `Token`: every Haskell value has precisely one type<sup>1</sup>, there's no such thing as OO-style subtyping in Haskell.

However, Haskell types (and not just functions, but anything!) may be polymorphic. And indeed, number literals *are* polymorphic:

> Prelude> :t 12
>   12 :: Num a => a

That means, if `Token` is a `Num` type, then `12` will actually be a correct value (it wouldn't have type `Int` then, but `Token` right away!). To achieve that, you can write

```
instance Num Token where
  fromInteger = Token . fromInteger
```

Strictly speaking, you should then also implement addition, absolute-value etc. for `Token`, which wouldn't come out very nice. Also, `(+)` would still not be valid in a `[Token]`. But you could write

```
tokens = [12, Operator(+)]
```

In fact, if this is supposed to be a very long list and you want to keep the code short, you could resort to a rather nasty trick that would allow you to write it exactly as you had originally:

```
mkToken :: TokenRep -> Token
mkToken f = f undefined undefined

type TokenRep = Token->Token->Token

instance Num Token where
  _ + _ = Operator (+)
  _ - _ = Operator (-)
  _ * _ = Operator (*)

instance Num TokenRep where       -- You need `-XFlexibleInstances` here
  fromInteger n _ _ = Value $ fromInteger n
```

and then

```
tokens = map mkToken [12, (+)]  -- Note that `12` has type `Token->Token->Token` here!
```

But really, this would be quite a horrible hack.

---

<sup>1</sup>A single type may have more than one name though: `[Char]` and `String` are actually *the very same type*, the latter is just defined as a synonym `type String = [Char]`. OTOH, with `data` or `newtype` you're always defining a *new* (duh) and thus separate type.

Comment: Thanks. This is slightly over my head, but it'll be useful to refer back to once I know a bit more about haskell.